# Structuring a server+frontend TS project in VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm writing a Node web app in Typescript using VSCode, and I also want to write my frontend code in Typescript.

What's the best way to structure my workspace/project in VSCode, so that it works well with VSCode's built-in tooling (compilation, different set of typings, etc.)?

Should I have two folders `front` and `server` at the root of my project? Should my `front` folder be a subfolder while `server` is the root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I have two folders front and server at the root of my project? Should my front folder be a subfolder while server is the root?

I prefer single `src` folder containing *everything* with frontend only code in `app` and common code in `common`

## Example

Checkout how [alm.tools](http://alm.tools/) is structured : https://github.com/alm-tools/alm/tree/master/src